# Product filter doesn't work after using JS function

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
<div id="column-1">
<div class="categories"></div>
</div>
```

and:

```
<div id="category-filter-wrapper">
some other div classses
</div>
```

The category filter is in #content wrapper (66% width) but I want to move it to #column-1 wrapper but if I use JS function below, filter not work, see [EXAMPLE](https://223833.myshoptet.com/modni-doplnky:fly-london/). You can click on the brands on the left but filter doesn't work but filter over the products works very well.

JS function I use:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ $('#category-filter-wrapper').insertBefore('#categories'); });
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ $('#category-filter-wrapper').insertBefore('#categories'); });
</script>
```

I am trying to make it work about 2 hours but don't know why it's not working if I just move it.

(Don't be rude about CSS styles, I need to make it work before I started to style it :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Try using .categories instead of #categories.

In selectorStrings:

HashTag (#) for IDs

Dot (.) for classes

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ $('#category-filter-wrapper').insertBefore('.categories'); });
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){ $('#category-filter-wrapper').insertBefore('.categories'); });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that'S not the problem. The problem will be in this JS, I think the filter script is there [link]https://223833.myshoptet.com/user/documents/upload/javascript.js